# Publish a change: error Command "publish-gh-pages" not found

Tags: yarnpkg, docusaurus

I was able to follow the guide and published this page: https://chengtie.github.io/docusaurus/docs/doc3/

Now, I want to do some small change. After changing code in my local folder. I did:

```
GIT_USER=chengtie \
  CURRENT_BRANCH=master \
  USE_SSH=true \
  yarn run publish-gh-pages
```

Then, I got an error:

```
yarn run v1.16.0
error Command "publish-gh-pages" not found.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

**Edit 1:**

```
Ties-MBP:my-website chengtie$ GIT_USER=chengtie   CURRENT_BRANCH=master   USE_SSH=true   yarn run deploy
yarn run v1.16.0
$ docusaurus deploy
Deploy command invoked ...
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
Creating an optimized production build...

Success! Generated static files in build.

Cloning into 'docusaurus-gh-pages'...
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Error: Error: git clone failed
    at build_1.build.then (/Users/chengtie/Downloads/my-website/node_modules/@docusaurus/core/lib/commands/deploy.js:84:23)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:81:5)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Here is `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "my-website",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "docusaurus": "docusaurus",
    "start": "docusaurus start",
    "build": "docusaurus build",
    "swizzle": "docusaurus swizzle",
    "deploy": "docusaurus deploy"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@docusaurus/core": "^2.0.0-alpha.24",
    "@docusaurus/preset-classic": "^2.0.0-alpha.24",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "react": "^16.8.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.4"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docusaurus maintainer here!

`yarn publish-gh-pages` is a V1 command. In V2 it should be `yarn deploy`. I see that your linked site is a V2 site. Refer to the deployment docs [here](https://v2.docusaurus.io/docs/deployment).

Try changing your command to:

```
GIT_USER=chengtie \
  CURRENT_BRANCH=master \
  USE_SSH=true \
  yarn run deploy
```

Also inspect your `package.json` and see what available npm scripts there are.

Comment: The doc I followed is this one: https://docusaurus.io/docs/en/installation. I still got an error with `yarn deploy`, please see the update...

Comment: You're referring to the V1 docs but you're using V2. V2 docs are here - https://v2.docusaurus.io/docs/deployment

Comment: @SoftTimur did that help? If so could you mark the answer as correct?

Comment: Actually, i really followed the doc of V1: https://docusaurus.io/docs/en/installation. But i will try completely V2. I will surely let you know...

Comment: By the way, do you have any idea about this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57339780/spaces-are-missing-in-the-layout?

Comment: You're using V2 (as seen in your `package.json`), so don't look at V1 docs at all. Thank you very much.