# Spaces are missing in the layout

Tags: docusaurus

I coded the following code in `.md`:

````
```bash
   =AND(a,AND(b,c,d),e) 
=> =AND(a,b,c,d,e)
```
````

However, the spaces before `=AND(a,AND(b,c,d),e)` are missing:

[image]

Does anyone know how to amend this?

Comment: This seems to be a bug in Docusaurus because we trim the start and ending trailing spaces. Please file a bug on our repo.

Comment: I just added an issue: https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/issues/1748